# Error Handling Spring JdbcTemplate batchUpdate

Tags: spring, error-handling, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am trying to update thousands of rows in a table using batchUpdate.  My requirements are:

1) Assume there are 1000 records in a  batch. Record No 235 caused an error.  How do I find out which record caused the error.

2) Assume that record 600 did not result in an update (reason could be no record matching the where clause).  How can I find out records that did not result in an update.

3) In both scenarios above how can I continue processing the remaining records.

Answer (score 7):

The only solution after long search and debug is to go to BatchUpdateException  class and find the negative element and deduce the value of the insertion that is in error from the MAP.

```
import java.sql.BatchUpdateException;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BatchPreparedStatementSetter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
@Repository("dao_")
public class YouDao extends CommunDao implements IyouDao {

    public void bulkInsert(final List<Map<String, String>> map)
            throws BusinessException { 
        try {

            String sql = " insert into  your_table " + "(  aa,bb  )"
                    + "values " + "(  ?,? )";
            BatchPreparedStatementSetter batchPreparedStatementSetter = new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                @Override
                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i)
                        throws SQLException {
                    Map<String, String> bean = map.get(i);

                    ps.setString(1, bean.get("aa"));
                    ps.setString(2, bean.get("bb")); 
                    //..
                    //..

                }

                @Override
                public int getBatchSize() {
                    return map.size();
                }
            };

             getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(sql, batchPreparedStatementSetter);

        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            if (e.getCause() instanceof BatchUpdateException) {
                BatchUpdateException be = (BatchUpdateException) e.getCause();
                int[] batchRes = be.getUpdateCounts();
                if (batchRes != null && batchRes.length > 0) {
                    for (int index = 0; index < batchRes.length; index++) {
                        if (batchRes[index] == Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED) {
                            logger.error("Error execution >>>>>>>>>>>"
                                    + index + " --- , codeFail : " + batchRes[index]
                                    + "---, line " + map.get(index));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }  
            throw new BusinessException(e);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I see you're catching a BatchUpdateException, but when I try to do that I get a syntax error, because it says none of the classes in the try actually throw it, which the documentation bears out. What's throwing your exception? (Is that why you're doing that getCause() stuff?)

Comment: @halfer I tried doing the same but I do not get the batch update exception itself, can you please help me out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65561067/how-to-capture-error-records-using-jdbctemplate-batchupdate-in-postgresql

Comment: @Sameer: I am an editor on this answer - I think your query is to question_maven_com. However, they haven't signed in for ~11 months.

Answer (score -5):

```
int[] rows =jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(TbCareQueryConstant.SQL_UPDATE_BANKDETAILS_OF_USER, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter(){

.....
your code


}

 for(int i=0 ; i < rows.length ; i++){
        
     if(rows[i] == 0){
         
           
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer contains only (poorly formatted)
 code, while lacking some sort of an explanation. I would suggest reading [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and then maybe editing the answer too.

Comment: This appears to be an incomplete answer, and so is worse than LQ. I tried to raise an NAA flag on this, but it was declined.