# Spring JDBCTemplate batch-insert WITHOUT transactional rollback (even if one or more records in batch fail)?

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-jdbc, rollback, batch-insert

I need to persist a list of objects in DB as a batched-insert, but don't want the entire batch to get rolled back if one/more of the objects fail; i.e. any records that were successfully saved should remain in DB.

Also, I need to identify IDs of objects that failed to be persisted, and return that list out to caller.

Following is a simple demo of what I need to do; shown are the Class of the object (a list of which I need to persist) and a fragment of the DAO method:

```
class Student {
    int code;
    String name;

    ...

}

   
public List<Integer> bulkAddStudents(List<Student> students) {

   String query = "INSERT INTO STUDENT (CODE, NAME) VALUES (:code, :name)";

   List<Integer> failedCodes = new LinkedList<Integer>(); // to store failed student-codes

   List<Map<String, Object>> params = new ArrayList<>();
   try {
       students.forEach(student -> {
          Map<String, Object> stu = new HashMap<>();
          stu.put("code", student.getCode());
          stu.put("name", student.getName());
          params.add(stu);
      });

      namedJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(query, params.toArray(new HashMap[0]));

      // TODO prevent transactional rollback for failed records

      // TODO get student numbers of failed records; add to "failedCodes" 

   } catch (Exception ex) {
      throw new DAOException(ex);
   }

   return failedCodes; // return IDs of failed records
}
```

This might not fit a common usecase, but does anyone know how to do exactly the above? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have any idea for actual answer of this question but.Maybe you can do it non-transactional.And detect which record had failed like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41662302/4212429

Comment: @seyidyagmur, thank you, that question has asked for the exact two things I need answers for. Let me try that out; I'll update this with the results.

Comment: UPDATE: The linked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41662302/4212429) above does not seem to proceed to persist the rest of the records in batch once it has encountered an exception. What I'm looking for is a way for all objects to be attempted to be persisted regardless of what/how many fail, and identify all records that failed.