# How to Capture error records using JDBCTemplate batchUpdate in postgreSql?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am using Spring JDBCTemplate and BatchPreparedStatementSetter to perform batch Update on a postgreSql DB. I wanted to capture the erroneous records and after going through some posts, found out that catching the BatchUpdateException and then looking for 'Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED' could help me identify the records that were erroneous. However, when I implement it as below, I never get a batchUpdate exception.

Here I am trying to enter the same id "120" repeatedly so that I get a unique constraint violation to force an exception at db level.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void batchInsertTenantPayloads(List<Payload> payloadMessages) {

    try {
        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(DBQueryConstants.INSERT_INTO_MESSAGE_METERING_PAYLOAD, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

            @Override
            public int getBatchSize() {
                return payloadMessages.size();
            }

            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
              
                ps.setLong(1, 120);
                ps.setString(2, payloadMessages.get(i).getId());
                ps.setDate(3, Date.valueOf(payloadMessages.get(i).getTs().toLocalDate()));
                ps.setString(4, payloadMessages.get(i).getContent().getId());
                ps.setInt(5, payloadMessages.get(i).getStatus().ordinal());
                ps.setString(6, MyUtils.toJSON(payloadMessages.get(i)));
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e.getCause() instanceof BatchUpdateException) {
            LOGGER.info("Batch exception occurred");
            BatchUpdateException be = (BatchUpdateException) e.getCause();
            int[] batchUpdateCounts = be.getUpdateCounts();
            for (int index = 0; index < batchUpdateCounts.length; index++) {
                if (batchUpdateCounts[index] == Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED) {
                    LOGGER.error(
                            "[MMC] batch update Error execution >>>>>>>>>>>" + index + " --- , codeFail : " + batchUpdateCounts[index]
                                    + "---, line " + payloadMessages.get(index));
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

The challenge is that I never enter the BatchUpdateException block.
Instead I get an

> org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException

and the nested exception is

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates
> unique constraint "message_metering_payload_pkey"

What can I do differently so that I can capture the batchUpdate exception and get just the error rows and commit the good ones.

My batch size is 500. Postgre version is 9.6 and I am using spring 2.0 with spring jdbc 5.1.3.

The stacktrace looks something like this

```
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [insert into message_metering_payload(id,tenant_name,source_dt,exchange_id,status,payload)values(?,?,?,?,?,?)]; ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "message_metering_payload_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id)=(120) already exists.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "message_metering_payload_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id)=(120) already exists.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:242)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1444)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:632)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:646)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:936)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not get `BatchUpdateException`, because you might use [`SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.html) in `jdbcTemplate`, which handles `BatchUpdateException`s [in a special way](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/44b29b6ecfdf77aec59409601301ca8e21452f0e/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/support/SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java#L179):

```java
if (sqlEx instanceof BatchUpdateException && sqlEx.getNextException() != null) {
    SQLException nestedSqlEx = sqlEx.getNextException();
    if (nestedSqlEx.getErrorCode() > 0 || nestedSqlEx.getSQLState() != null) {
        sqlEx = nestedSqlEx;
    }
}
```

There is an issue about it:

- [jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate does not return counters of the BatchUpdateException](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23867)

You can mitigate this, if you use the [`SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.html):

```java
jdbcTemplate.setExceptionTranslator(new SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator());
```

Then you will get the `BatchUpdateException` as a `cause`:

```java
try {
    // ...
} catch (DataAccessException e) {
    Throwable cause = e.getCause();
    logger.info("cause instanceof BatchUpdateException = {}", cause instanceof BatchUpdateException);
 }
```

**But** note that in case of postgresql jdbc driver `BatchUpdateException#getUpdateCounts()` will contain [`EXECUTE_FAILED`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#EXECUTE_FAILED) only, despite the fact that some row could be inserted successfully.

See [this](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/670) issue

Comment: Does changing the SQLExceptionTranslator have other side effects, like change in behaviour of transactional or any other side effect other than how exceptions are propagated that i should be concerned about?

Comment: It should not affect anything _other than `SQLException` translation strategy_, everything else should remain unaffected

Comment: I see that even the non erroneous rows come up as status -3. Is there a way to avoid this and only get the wrrnous rows?

Comment: It does not seem to be possible. See [this](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/670) issue. What kind of errors do you have in your batch? Isn't [`on conflict do nothing`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) an option for you?

Comment: The unique constraint violation is just an example. I am performing a batch update of 500 records, currently on an exception, I rollback the transaction and then add the records one by one. The idea was if i could get the committed records, then I could simply ignore the error ones and try and recommit thee good ones. Let's say if only one record in 500 that files, then I could just identify that one record and commit the remaining.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know a straightforward way to do it easily. Some of suggestions are in [the comments of issue](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/670#issuecomment-255353583)